# Como adicionar "Reply To" com Nome e E-mail do Cliente WooCommerce

Tags: php, email, woocommerce

Olá,

Estou com um problemão nesta parte, eu gostaria de setar o nome do Cliente ao invés de somente o E-mail ao clicar em Responder.
Abaixo o código que usei para funcionar "Reply To":

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'add_reply_to_wc_admin_new_order', 10, 3 );

function add_reply_to_wc_admin_new_order( $headers = '', $id = '', $order ) {
    if ( $id == 'new_order' ) {
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$order->billing_email."\r\n"; 
    }
   return $headers;
}
```

Como podem ver este código funciona da seguinte maneira, ao responder o E-mail de novo pedido do WooCommerce ele irá responder ao E-mail do Cliente preenchido no Formulário de Cobrança da Loja. Eu gostaria de colocar também o nome do Cliente.

Um exemplo sobre o qual estou tentando explicar é do PHPMailer que funciona desta maneira:

```
$mailer->AddReplyTo($_POST["email"], $_POST["nome"]);
```

Neste modelo do PHPMailer ao clicar em responder ele faz mais ou menos isso:

```
Rodrigo Macedo <mail@domain.com>,
```

Será que alguém tem uma ideia de como posso fazer isso ?

Já tentei adicionar de várias formas o código no nome na frente do E-mail parecido com o do PHPMailer porém sem sucesso...

Comment: A pergunta me parece ok, como vc faz para pegar o nome do cliente? é o `$_POST["nome"]` mesmo?

Comment: @rray Então, este foi um exemplo que dei, e quanto a sua pergunta, é isso mesmo, este código é usado pra pegar o nome do cliente que ele preenche no formulário, este código é pelo PHPMailer que uso para envio de formulários autenticados em meus Websites, no caso eu quero fazer a mesma coisa no formulário do WooCommerce porém como não tenho muito conhecimento em programação não estou conseguindo..

Answer (score 1):

Da mesma forma que você insere o e-mail do cliente:

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: email@email.com";
```

Você deve inserir o nome dentro de um padrão que você mesmo informou:

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: Nome Cliente <email@email.com>";
```

Caso queira enviar para mais alguém, adicione vírgulas:

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: Nome Cliente <email@email.com>, Segundo Cliente <email@email.com>";
```

Pode, também, ser verificado nos comentários do manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#108368

Comment: Brother, seu código estaria perfeito se fosse só colocar o E-mail do Cliente e Nome na frente como disse, mas tem um porém, eu estou fazendo isso no fomulário do WooCommerce e pra pegar o E-mail do Cliente tenho que usar o seguinte código: $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$order->billing_email."\r\n"; O problema é eu colocar o nome do cliente, eu tentei o seguinte: $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$order->billing_name."".$order->billing_email."\r\n"; Porém o envio não é realizado...

Comment: @RoohMacedo Segundo seu código, está faltando os [chevrons](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevron_(tipografia)) (<>) no e-mail. Essa é a forma padrão, não tem como não funcionar.

Comment: Então eu tentei adicionar de várias formas os chevrons (<>), adicionei das seguintes formas: 1ª $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$order->billing_name.""<.$order->billing_email.>"\r\n"; 2ª $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$order->billing_name. <.$order->billing_email.>"\r\n"; //Sem as aspas entre os dois. e por útlimo 3ª $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$order->billing_name."<".$order->billing_email.">"\r\n"; Mas nenhum dos modos que tentei funcionou, há algo de errado ?

Comment: Com a exceção de faltar um espaço entre o nome e o chevron. Em teoria, o correto seria (o código varia, considere apenas o resultado): `"Reply-To: {$name} <{$e-mail}>"` para ter o resultado como `"Reply-To: Nome Cliente <email@email.com>"`. Qual é o resultado que está obtendo? Algum erro, vai sem o nome? Crie a string e de um `var_dump($headers);` para ver como ficou formatado.

Comment: Ainda to aprendendo sobre esse assunto, como faço pra criar essa string e dar esse var_dump ? Eu tentei da seguinte forma: $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$order->billing_first_name."<".$order->billing_email.">\r\n"; Porém dessa forma ele não pegou o nome do Cliente, foi só o E-mail, ai quando clico em responder no E-mail ele pega somente o E-mail do Cliente.

Comment: Acabei de fazer da forma como você informou acima: $headers .= "Reply-To: {$order->billing_first_name} <{$order->billing_email}> \r\n"; Porém só veio o E-mail do Cliente, nada do Nome..

Comment: É importante estudar sobre [concatenação de strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). Como está usando aspas duplas, eu faria assim `$headers .= "Reply-To: {$order->billing_first_name} <{$order->billing_email}>\r\‌n";`. O var_dump seria na variável $headers, antes do return $headers, para verificar como está sendo formatada a string.

Comment: Acabei de comentar rsrs, fiz dessa forma que você formatou o código, porém veio só o E-mail, o nome não veio, será que é melhor eu criar essa `var_dump` que você disse ?